# Spring Boot PagingAndSortingRepository Custom Sort

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot for developing microservices. I am using `PagingAndSortingRepository` to fetch entity data from database. I have a requirement to sort the data using a custom sort order.

For example - This is the sort order provided for a column, ascending order - BBB+, BBB, BBB- (there will be some more values here)

But by tradition, when executing order by query on the column with above values the ascending order will be - BBB, BBB+, BBB-

Using below query I can achieve it:

```
select value from (select value, decode(value, 'BBB+', 1, 'BBB', 2, 'BBB-', 3) value_weightage from table) order by value_weightage;
```

Is there a way I can achieve this spring boot `PagingAndSortingRepository` by defining weightage to the values ?

One way is I can add the query directly as native query and get it sorted. But wanted to know the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated property using a Hibernate `@Formula` in your entity:

```
@Formula("decode(value, 'BBB+', 1, 'BBB', 2, 'BBB-', 3)") // native sql
private int weightedValue;
```

And refer to it when specifying the sort order:

```
var sort = Sort.by("weightedValue").descending();
var pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10, sort);
var pageResult = repository.findAll(pageable);
```